# Goldbach’s Conjecture in Python

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, python-3.x, primes

**Input Format**

Input starts with an integer n (1 ≤ n ≤ 100) indicating the number of cases. The following n lines each contain a test case of a single even number x (4 ≤ x ≤ 32000).

**Output Format**

For each test case x, give the number of unique ways that x can be represented as a sum of two primes. Then list the sums (one sum per line) in increasing order of the first addend. The first addend must always be less than or equal to the second to avoid duplicates.

**Sample Input**

```
2
26
100
```

**Sample Output**

```
26 has 3 representation(s)
3+23
7+19
13+13
```

The above problem was originally posted in 2013 ICPC North America Qualifier, I encountered it in [HackerRank's Round-I Holiday Cup contest](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/round-1-holiday-cup/challenges/goldbachs-conjecture).

**My Python 3.x Code**

```
import math
import time
def sieve(n):
    "Return all primes <= n using sieve of erato."
    np1 = n + 1
    s = list(range(np1))
    s[1] = 0
    sqrtn = int(round(n**0.5))
    for i in range(2, sqrtn + 1):
        if s[i]:
            s[i*i: np1: i] = [0] * len(range(i*i, np1, i))
    return filter(None, s)
def primeSum(n):
    p=2
    limit=math.floor(n/2)
    for p in primes:
        q=n-p
        if(p>q):
            break
        if(q in primes):
            out.extend([p,q])
    print (n,"has",round(len(out)/2),"representation(s)")
    for i,j in zip(out[0::2],out[1::2]):
        print (i,"+",j,sep='')

    print ("")

primes = sorted(set(sieve(32000)))
for __ in range(int(input())):
    out = []
    primeSum(int(input()))
```

This code almost took over 5 seconds for larger values of n but ran less than second in most cases. Is it because of time taken to output all those representations for larger values (because 32000 has over 300 representations.

Can this be optimized? and also review my general coding (I'm new to python).

Comment: Apparently there is a bug. It shows 0 representations for 125.

Comment: Yea because Goldbach's conjecture is all about evens and primes. It says if n is even it can be represented as n=p+q where both p and q are primes.

Comment: Oops... I don't know what I was thinking about. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the problem well enough to tell you how to improve the speed of the logic, but yes your print calls are slow. `print` can actually be quite a slow command (it depends on where you're running it).

But there is a way to speed it up without reducing text, and it suits your purposes. If you make less print calls with longer strings, you can reduce the time it takes. And in your case this also means replacing a for loop with a generator expression, which is also good. Generator expressions are list like objects that pass out one value at a time to a function or a loop.

So here's the code we can improve:

```
for i,j in zip(out[0::2],out[1::2]):
    print (i,"+",j,sep='')
```

You're iterating over pairs and printing each time, but with the `str.join` command you could use that `for` loop setup to instead make one long string that contains all the results. To make it a generator first the print arguments need to be switched to just a normal string formation, like this:

```
("{}+{}".format(i, j))
```

`i` and `j` will be swapped in where those curly braces are, making the same string you were printing with `sep=''`. Now here's how the generator expression looks:

```
("{}+{}".format(i, j) for i, j in zip(out[0::2], out[1::2]))
```

I have changed the string, but you can see that the for loop is just the same as before. Now to actually turn this into a string, we need to pass it to `"".join`. `join` is called on a string object, and whatever you put in that string object is inserted between each value taken from the generator. Since each print is a new line, a newline character fits best:

```
print(n, "has", round(len(out) / 2), "representation(s)")
results = ("{}+{}".format(i, j) for i, j in zip(out[0::2], out[1::2]))
print('\n'.join(results))
```

This may not solve your full speed problem, but it is faster and is a cleaner way to format the code.

Comment: This is what actually solved the speed problem!

Answer (score 4):

**Pass more arguments to functions**

`primes` is global, but passing it as an argument to `primeSum` is trivial:

```
def primeSum(n, primes):
```

and then:

```
primeSum(int(input()), primes)
```

This makes the reasoning about and testing the function easier.

**Do not modify random global variables**

`out.extend([p,q])` where `out` is a global variable. Don't. It makes the code impossible to use in different situations and therefore wastes your programming effort.

**Do not print from a computation function**

`primeSum` should find a prime sum. Printing the couples nicely is the job for another function. Again a computer friendly return format improves re-usability.

**Remove dead code**

You write:

```
limit=math.floor(n/2)
```

But `limit` is never been used, so delete that line.

Also `p=2` can be eliminated as it does nothing.

**Meaningful names**

Avoid single-letter names, be descriptive. Good names can really make the difference between un-readable and readable code. And remember to use `snake_case` in Python.

**Final version**

Putting all my advice together gives this nice `prime_sum` function:

```
def prime_sums(number, primes):
    """
    Checks how a number may be written as a sum of two primes.

    >>> list(prime_sums(100, sorted(set(sieve(100)))))
    [(3, 97), (11, 89), (17, 83), (29, 71), (41, 59), (47, 53)]
    """
    for prime in primes:
        difference = number - prime
        if(prime > difference):
            break
        if(difference in primes):
            yield (prime, difference)
```

Comment: Hmm..I agree as it was a contest I tried to shorten the code. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Actually I have not learnt to use yield, I'll look into it!

Comment: @Protino it is a sleek way of returning a list from a function basically. Stackoverflow explain it very well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python

Comment: @oliverpool Sure

Comment: I love doing code review review ^^ (I deleted the comments that you fixed)

Answer (score 2):

Here are some comments:

- **Cut out unused code.** A few instances I spotted:

  ```
  import time  # The time module is never used
  limit=math.floor(n/2)  # We never use this variable
  ```
- **Read [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the Python style guide.** I’m not going to break it down in detail, but among other things:

  - Spaces around binary operators
  - Function names should be lowercase_with_underscores, not camelCase as in `primeSum()`.
  - Two newlines between functions.
- **Use better variable names.** Names like p, q and s aren’t very helpful – single-letter variable names rarely are. You should give them meaningful names, that tell me what the value represents in the original problem.
- **Rethink how the primeSum() function works.** Right now, it manipulates an external list (`out`) and prints some stuff to the screen. The printing is unhelpful if I want to use this as part of a larger function (not reusable), and it’s trusting the caller to set up a list called `out`. It would be better if:

  - It didn’t print anything
  - It created a new, empty version of `out` as an internal list, and returned that

  Subsequent invocations will do weird things with the contents of `out`.
- **More comments and docstrings.** There’s only one docstring in this function, and it’s quite short. You should bulk up the docstrings, telling me what the function does, what inputs it takes, and what the meaning of the return value is.

  There should also be some comments relating the code back to the original problem. This is really important for reading, reviewing and maintainability. (Starting example: why do you set `s[1]` to be `0` on line 7? This isn’t obvious to somebody who only has the code.)
- **Tidy up the computation of the sqrtn variable.**

  - Rather than using `n**0.5`, use `math.sqrt(n)`. Slightly longer, but more explicit.
  - Once you’ve called `round()`, you don’t need to cast to int. Quoting [from the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html?highlight=round#round):

    > The return value is an integer if called with one argument, otherwise of the same type as number.

    (Note this behaviour is new with Python 3.)
  - Since this variable is only used once, I’d inline it with the range() on the next line.

Answer (score 1):

Building on top of what was already pointed out in the other posts, there are a couple of optimizations to be made.

**Set operations in place of iterating list**

You are creating a `list` of `sorted` primes after calling `set` on the original `list` from your sieve and then using that primes `list` to check for members in your main loop:

```
for p in primes:
    q=n-p
    if(p>q):
        break
    if(q in primes):
        out.extend([p,q])
```

In the trimmed down sample below, you can save a copy of that call to `set` while still iterating in the `sorted` primes `list` but checking for membership using the `set` logical operations:

```
pset = set(sieve(32000))
primes = sorted(pset)
```

then the loop is:

```
for p in primes:
    q=n-p
    if(p>q):
        break
    if {q} & pset:
        out.extend([p,q])
```

This is improving the overall time by about two orders of magnitude:

```
import math
import time

from timeit import default_timer


def sieve(n):
    "Return all primes <= n using sieve of erato."
    np1 = n + 1
    s = list(range(np1))
    s[1] = 0
    sqrtn = int(round(n**0.5))
    for i in range(2, sqrtn + 1):
        if s[i]:
            s[i*i: np1: i] = [0] * int(math.ceil((np1 - i*i) / i))
    return filter(None, s)

def primeSum(n):
    p=2
    for p in primes:
        q=n-p
        if(p>q):
            break
        if {q} & pset:
            out.extend([p,q])

pset = set(sieve(32000))
primes = sorted(pset)

test_runs = 20
total = 0

for _ in range(test_runs):
    out = []
    start = default_timer()
    primeSum(30000)
    stop = default_timer()
    total += (stop - start)
print('Total Time: {:4f}'.format(total))
print('Avg Testrun Time: {:4f}'.format(total / test_runs))
```

Results in:

```
Total Time: 0.027330
Avg Testrun Time: 0.001367
```

Where, a trimmed down version of your original (minus the `print` calls):

```
import math
import time

from timeit import default_timer


def sieve(n):
    "Return all primes <= n using sieve of erato."
    np1 = n + 1
    s = list(range(np1))
    s[1] = 0
    sqrtn = int(round(n**0.5))
    for i in range(2, sqrtn + 1):
        if s[i]:
            s[i*i: np1: i] = [0] * len(range(i*i, np1, i))
    return filter(None, s)

def primeSum(n):
    p=2
    limit=math.floor(n/2)
    for p in primes:
        q=n-p
        if(p>q):
            break
        if(q in primes):
            out.extend([p,q])

primes = sorted(set(sieve(32000)))

test_runs = 20
total = 0

for _ in range(test_runs):
    out = []
    start = default_timer()
    primeSum(30000)
    stop = default_timer()
    total += (stop - start)
print('Total Time: {:4f}'.format(total))
print('Avg Testrun Time: {:4f}'.format(total / test_runs))
```

Runs in:

```
Total Time: 7.038189
Avg Testrun Time: 0.351909
```

Note: this code is run with *python3.5*

**Math operation instead of useless object creation**

I calculate the length of the sequence to be added in the sieve:

```
s[i*i: np1: i] = [0] * int(math.ceil((np1 - i*i) / i))
```

Instead of calling `len` over a `range` object you won't use:

```
s[i*i: np1: i] = [0] * len(range(i*i, np1, i))
```

Comment: Verify the Total time of my code without print calls, it is actually around `1.8s` and not `7.038s`. Combining your code and @SuperBiasedMan 's output formatting it just takes `0.28s`

Comment: @Protino did you factor in that `7.038` was the total aggregate time from 20 tests run?  The bottom value of `0.35` was the average I got from your code without `print` calls

Comment: yes the total time is `1.870s` and Avg is `0.09s`I verified it on my windows 32-bit python platform.  Do re-run it and verify.

Comment: I've retested and the code in the answer above matches up to the results I'm getting (copy-pasted as is the sample on 32-bit archlinux).  Possibly you could put a link to a paste?

Comment: It takes `2.8s` in [http://ideone.com/MwHG9u ](Ideone)

Comment: You should grab a copy of `python3.5` and give this a try!  I ran the ideone code and sure enough it was timed as you said  ~2.8s.  I re-ran the code in my system but, still got the same results of ~7.0.  I started to get suspicious of the version numbers here and saw ideone was using `python3.4`.  I'm running archlinux and `python3.5` is installed so, I grabbed a copy of 3.4 and the results matched yours and ideone.  Really strange that the results would vary that much.

Comment: @Protino I will make a note of the version numbers in the answer.

Comment: Anyways I got awesome results in HackerRank though. I combined all the suggestions provided here and the code ran in less than `0.06s` for a test case involving `100 test runs!.` Cheers.